# Unmarshal nested structs and type assertion

Tags: pointers, go, interface, linked-list, unmarshalling

I want to Marshal and Unmarshal a binary tree like structure in Go. Each node corresponds to a struct of type Node. Nodes are interconnected through pointers (left and right children), much like in a linked list. The tree's leaves carry content which is implemented as an interface. All leaves of a tree have the same type of Content which is known to the unmarshaler beforehand.
I know that when Unmarshaling a struct with an interface in one field (say "Content"), I have to do a type assertion like
`err = json.Unmarshal(byteSlice, &decodedStruct{Content: &MyStruct{}})`
However, as the tree is of arbitrary size, my structs are deeply nested.
Is there a straightforward/idiomatic way of Marshaling/Unmarshaling such an object I am not aware of?

Below, I post a minimal example which I believe represents the two key features of first, a sequence of pointers and second, an interface at the "end".
(playground: https://play.golang.org/p/t9C9Hn4ONlE )

```
// LinkedList is a simple linked list defined by a root node
type LinkedList struct {
    Name string
    Root *Node
}

// Node is a list's node with Content
type Node struct {
    Child *Node
    C     Content
}

// Content is a dummy interface
type Content interface {
    CalculateSum() int
}

// MyStruct implements Content
type MyStruct struct {
    ID     int
    Values []int
}

// CalculateSum computes the sum of the slice in the field @Values
func (ms MyStruct) CalculateSum() (s int) {
    for _, i := range ms.Values {
        s += i
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    // Make a list of three nodes with content in the leaf
    ms := MyStruct{2, []int{2, 4, 7}}
    leaf := Node{nil, ms}
    node := Node{&leaf, nil}
    rootNode := Node{&node, nil}
    ll := LinkedList{"list1", &rootNode}

    // Encoding linked list works fine...
    llEncoded, err := json.Marshal(ll)

    // ...decoding doesn't:
    // error decoding:  json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Node.Root.Child.Child.C of type main.Content
    llDecoded := LinkedList{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(llEncoded, &llDecoded)
    fmt.Println("error decoding: ", err)
}
```

Comment: Is every `Content` a `MyStruct`? If not, if you have more types implementing `Content`, how then do you know which leaf should be which type? And how do you plan on "telling" that to the unmarshaler?

Comment: @mkopriva: Thanks for the question. I should have mentioned that and amended the post accordingly.

Comment: @jppade: ?? I didn't ask a question.

Comment: @jppade Are you saying that the concrete value in `Node.C` is always a `*MyStruct`?

Comment: @MuffinTop No, it can be anything that implements Content. But I know what type it is when marshaling/unmarshaling.

Comment: @jppade Is there a single concrete type for the entire tree, or do you know the concrete type per node?  If it's per node, how do you discover the type?

Comment: @MuffinTop Yes, single concrete type per tree. All nodes have nil content except for the  leaves which all have the same type of content per tree; and which I know from some other part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `Content`'s concrete type upfront you can implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface, unmarshaling into the hard-coded concrete type and then assign the result to the interface type.

```
func (n *Node) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var node struct {
        Child *Node
        C     *MyStruct
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &node); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    n.Child = node.Child
    n.C = node.C
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/QOJuiLpYrze

---

If you need it to be more flexible you'll need to somehow tell the `json.Unmarshaler` implementation what concrete type the json represents. One way you could do this is to embed type information into the content's json, for example (now with the help of the `json.Marshaler` interface):

```
func (ms MyStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type _MyStruct MyStruct

    var out = struct {
        Type string `json:"_type"`
        _MyStruct
    }{
        Type:      "MyStruct",
        _MyStruct: _MyStruct(ms),
    }
    return json.Marshal(out)
}
```

Update the `Node`'s unmarshaler implementation accordingly:

```
func (n *Node) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var node struct {
        Child *Node
        C     json.RawMessage
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &node); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    n.Child = node.Child

    if len(node.C) > 0 && string(node.C) != `null` {
        var _type struct {
            Type string `json:"_type"`
        }
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(node.C), &_type); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        c := newContent[_type.Type]()
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(node.C), c); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        n.C = c
    }
    return nil
}
```

and define the `newContent` as a map whose values are functions that return new instances of the concrete type:

```
var newContent = map[string]func() Content{
    "MyStruct": func() Content { return new(MyStruct) },
    // ...
}
```

Try it on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/u9L0VxEG4dT

Comment: I wasn't aware you could overwrite the unmarshaler. This seems to solve my problem. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @jppade i've added another approach that's more flexible.